# Passing Razor MVC Form to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table [image: here] in which each row has a jQuery datepicker in the last cell. Along with a submit button labeled 'Update'. The last cell also contains the Issue.ID in a hidden textbox. I am trying to retrieve these values in my controller but I get a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. 
Here is part of my view:

```
@foreach (Issue issue in Model.IssueSet.IssueList)
        {
            <tr class="altsec" id="@issue.RowID">
            <td>@issue.Zone.ToString()</td>
            <td>@issue.Station.ToString()</td>
            <td>@issue.WhenOpened.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
            <td>@issue.What.ToString()</td>
            <td>@issue.Why.ToString()</td>
            <td>@issue.How.ToString()</td>
            <td>@issue.Who.ToString()</td>
            <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" style="width: 100px; display: none" value="@issue.ID" name="stringID"/>
                    <input class="datepicker" type='text' style="width: 100px" id="@issue.DateID" />
                    <input class="updateButtons" type="submit" value="Update" /></fieldset>
            }</td>
           </tr>
        }
```

My controller for POST is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string stringID)
    {
        var ID = Request.Form[0].ToString();
        var date = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form[1]);

        string strSQL = "UPDATE bp_open_issues SET WhenFixed = '" + date + "' WHERE ID = '" + ID + "' ";
        SqlConnection con =
                new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.67.XX.XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX111; User Id=XXXXXX; Password=XXXXXX;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        TempData["msg"] = "<script>alert('Change succesfully');</script>";
        return Redirect("/");
    }
```

Comment: Your datepicker input does not contain a `name` attribute o its value is never submitted. And you should add the ID as a route value rather than using a hidden input. But your implementation only allows you to submit one row at a time and is a confusing UI. You should consider one form and allowing the user to select a date in all rows and update the whole collection in one action.

Comment: In any case, using `var ID = Request.Form[0].ToString();` is pointless - you already have that value - its bound to the parameter `stringID` and you should have a similar `DateTime` parameter for the date. But that will not solve other issues such as a user entering an invalid date. You should be using a view model and including client and server side validation.